# Selenium IDE fails getElementById()

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, selenium-ide

I have the following statement in my `Selenium IDE` script:
I 
    
        store
        javascript{window.document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML}
        text

But this always fails with the error

> [info] Executing: |store | javascript{window.document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML} | text |
>   [error] Unexpected Exception: TypeError: window.document.getElementById(...) is null.

The HTML source code I am using is from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_getelementbyid). The corresponding HTML source is

```
<p id="demo">Click the button to change the text in this paragraph.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>
```

There is no problem when I execute just

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>javascript{window.document.innerHTML}</td>
    <td>text</td>
</tr>
```

but trying to retrieve an element by its id is not working. What am I missing?

Comment: Actually you are using main document while desire I'd element is inside an iframe you need to call `getElementById` on iframe document...as `window.frame["demo_frame"].document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";`...:)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur This just returns `[error] Threw an exception: window.frame is undefined`.

Comment: Sorry it `window.frames`...just typo mistake..

Comment: @SaurabhGaur It is still failing: `[error] Threw an exception: window.frames.iframeResult.document is undefined`. I also tried with `frames[0]` and `frames[1]`. It then throws the `null` exception again.

Comment: Try once as `document.getElementById("iframe Id").contentDocument.getElementById("demo").i‌​nnerHTML = "Hello World";` and let me know...:)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur Your last suggestion worked. If you want to make your last comment an answer then I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Ya sure, I have provided it as an answer, you can accept it. Thanks..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you are using main `document` while desire I'd element is inside an `iframe` you need to call `getElementById` on `iframe` `document` as below :-

```
document.getElementById("iframe Id").contentDocument.getElementById("demo").i‌​nnerHTML = "Hello World";
```

Comment: please could u help me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47944349/selenium-cannot-click-on-an-element-inside-a-modal I am struggling since 2 days