# Selenium - cannot click on an element inside a modal

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I am using Selenium and java and I cannot click on an element inside a modal.
The scenario is this:
after clicking on an item inside a frame, it opens up a modal and I need to click on an element inside this modal but I cannot get it.

I already tried with:

```
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('saveexit').scrollIntoView(true);");
```

I also tried with switchTo() this way:

```
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    String popup =  itr.next();
    System.out.println("itr: " + popup);
    driver.switchTo().window(popup);
}
```

Here is the html of my modal:

```
<div class="modal-dialog">

    <div class="modal-content modal-custom-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="formTo" class="form-container">
                <div class="row">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="small-space"></div>
                <input ...>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        ...
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        ...
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        ...
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        ...
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="small-space"></div>
                <div class="row"> 
                    ...
                </div> 
            </form> 
        </div>
        <div class="small-space"></div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="row text-center"> 
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <button class="btn modal-button full-btn" id="saveexit" type="button">SAVE AND EXIT</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the CSS Path as taken from firefox dev tool:

```
html.no-touch body div.remodal-wrapper.remodal-is-opened div.modaliAdesione.remodal.remodal-is-initialized.remodal-is‌​-opened div.modal-dialog div.modal-content.modal-custom-content div.modal-footer div.row.text-center div.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-12 button#saveexit.btn.modal-button.full-btn
```

the object is never found.

- Question 1: if an element is inside a modal has to be managed
  differently?
- Question 2: How to finally have the click on the button
  **saveexit** working?

here is shared a code snippet of the html: https://codeshare.io/arLW9q

Here is the java code:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"saveexit\"]")))
```

I have also tried with:

```
cssSelector: #saveexit
cssPath: html.no-touch body div.remodal-wrapper.remodal-is-opened div.modaliAdesione.remodal.remodal-is-initialized.remodal-is-opened 
div.modal-dialog div.modal-content.modal-custom-content div.modal-footer div.row.text-center div.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-12 
button#saveexit.btn.modal-button.full-btn
xpath: //*[@id="saveexit"]
```

Please note: if I run `document.getElementById('saveexit').click();` from browser's console it works out

Comment: A modal isn't a window that can be switched to. It's just HTML on the page. What Java code have you tried and what was the result? Error messages, etc.

Comment: The Java code I tried is js.executeScript... the result is Simply an error saying that saveexit does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it using jquery inside my script;

here is the linecode:

`js.executeScript("$('#saveexit').trigger('click');");`

I hope it can help someone in future.

I dont know why plain javascript was not working...

Answer (score 1):

As you are using the **`Selenium-Java`** clients as per best practices the first and foremost trial must be with invoking the highly efficient and proven **`click()`** method. Depending on the errors resulting out of **`click()`** method we can work on other alternate solutions.

As I can see from your code trials with `JavascriptExecutor` and `switchTo().window()`, you havn't identified the `WebElement` representing the **`SAVE AND EXIT`** button well.

To click on the **`SAVE AND EXIT`** button you can use the following code block :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='modal-dialog']//div[@class='modal-footer']//button[@class='btn modal-button full-btn' and @id='saveexit']"))).click();
```

Comment: Thanks Deb, I Will try It ASAP and accept if It works

Comment: it does not work, having this  "Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath:..."

Comment: Show us a bit more of the `outerHTML`. Possible element is within an `iframe` or `xpath` is not unique.

Comment: this is the CSS Path as taken from firefox dev tool: html.no-touch body div.remodal-wrapper.remodal-is-opened div.modaliAdesione.remodal.remodal-is-initialized.remodal-is-opened div.modal-dialog div.modal-content.modal-custom-content div.modal-footer div.row.text-center div.col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-12 button#saveexit.btn.modal-button.full-btn

Comment: Update the main question with the info for SO volunteers to help you out.