# Selenium-python2.7: click on a modal table checkbox (following Selenium IDE)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I think my question is somehow related to this post
[Selenium - cannot click on an element inside a modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47944349/selenium-cannot-click-on-an-element-inside-a-modal)

I click on a an element and it opens a modal table. Then, I would like to select a particular checknox in a long list but Selenium gives me back an error.

That's what I did:

I tested first with Selenium IDE: first I recorded the operations but when I try to replay them in the log I get this:

```
Running 'Step2_sele'
1.open on /reserve-space/... OK
2.click on css=a[title="Locations"] > span... OK
3.click on linkText=Add/Remove Locations... OK
4.Trying to find xpath=//input[@value='2427']... Failed:
Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
```

I thought I should have given more time to the element to show up and I wrote this with Python

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url_res)
time.sleep(10)
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('a[title="Locations"]>span').click()
time.sleep(10)
browser.find_element_by_css_selector('a.dynamic-filter-item-add.summary').click()
time.sleep(10)
browser.find_element_by_xpath("xpath=//input[@value='2427']").click()
```

But I get this other error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 69, in <module>
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("xpath=//input[@value='2427']").click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 393, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 966, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression xpath=//input[@value='2427'] because of the following error:
TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type.
  (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

This is a screenshot of how the html code look like because I cannot post the real url [image]

Comment: Why did you add `"xpath="` to your XPath? What do you think it should do?

Comment: I'm very new to Selenium and HTML, I think I have done some cut and paste from the wrong example. I don't see any other explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the xpath string causes the problem. If my assumption is correction, the following should work:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='2427']").click()
```